# Css not working in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-float

In chrome my website is cramped at the bottom.

I have used a clear float to clear it and it works in Firefox but in Chrome, the bottom is all cramped? (I'll not mention IE because haven't tested yet but can fix for IE just don't know how to for Chrome)

http://justbedroomdesigns.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change css to this,

```
.post-block {
    width: 370px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    padding: 5px 2px 2px 2px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should correct the errors in your HTML first. For instance, decide if it should be HTML or XHTML, never reuse ID values, etc. If the problems still occur, ask again.

Comment: i'm confused.. i use inline clear both and external css.. is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the multiple ids. for instance, `id="photo"` occurs four times. That is a no-no!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this short post:

http://www.minitek.gr/tutorials/css-tutorials/item/12-how-to-fix-google-chrome-css?.html

More about Chrome rendering  can be found here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

One problem that I had with Chrome CSS is that when page is loaded locally (using XAMPP) it looks different
than when it's loaded from server.